# Перекрытие слоев друг другом

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Есть слои (`CALayer`) в виде частично перекрывающих друг друга кружков, собранных во вращающийся большой круг.
Каждый кружок перекрывает на 0.5 радиуса следующий за ним, и в свою очередь перекрывается предыдущим. Таким образом, не должно быть кружка, который не перекрывается или перекрывается с двух сторон.

Как сделать так, чтобы слои друг друга перекрывали описанным образом?

[image: как это должно выглядеть]

Comment: А что вы попробовали на данный момент?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Клади один на другой, а у последнего придется кусок первого отрендерить видимо

Comment: iFreeman, каким образом можно было бы один слой завернуть под другой не нарушая перекрытие с предыдущим?

Answer (score 1):

1. Пробовал работать со слоем как с двумя частями (добавив два подслоя).

   Изменяя значения .zPosition хотел добиться того чтобы левая часть отображалась поверху, а правая понизу.
2. Пробовал решить проблему используя кривую Безье.

   Надеялся на помощь .clipsToBounds = YES

   Задумка состояла в том чтобы также разбить слой на две части(правую и левую).

   Используя кривую Безье(овальной формы) отсечь в правой части всё что выступало .masksToBounds = YES.

   Затем, объединив слои, избавиться от правого слоя при помощи removeFromSuperlayer.

   Получил бы круг с вырезанной частью.

Но, ввиду не понимания работы используемых вещей, в этом деле не преуспел.

Хотелось бы узнать как это можно сделать по-другому, либо что я делал не так.

---

Манипулируя с параметрами .zPosition целых слоёв добился того что менялось их положение относительно друг друга (выше/ниже).

Однако, добавление подслоёв, либо же слоёв от subview с изменёнными .zPosition не изменяли положение слоя относительно других.

**Хотел добавить подслой (правой стороны) который бы рисовался поверх всех остальных.**

Структура такова что имея UIImageView* imageView получаем его слой:

CALayer* layer = [imageView layer]

Тогда вопрос следующий:

**Как добавить подслой(правой половины), либо же subview со своим слоем так чтобы он рисовался поверх остальных слоёв?**

Comment: Все слои кроме CATransformLayer имеют постоянную Z, поэтому да, подход с вырезанием лучше всего. Вам не нужно создавать новые слои и делать clipToBounds или masksToBounds = YES. Сейчас попробую сделать тестовый апп и сообщу

Comment: Самое что интересное, когда я манипулирую значением .zPosition с целыми слоями (не разбитыми на две части) - они изменяют перекрытие друг относительно друга, даже несмотря на то что они CALayer.